# On Ubuntu 18.04, i cannot access Tomcat from a browser using IP address

Tags: linux, tomcat, ubuntu-18.04

I've installed Tomcat 9 on Ubuntu 18.04(VM). I cannot access tomcat using IP address from a browser (or curl)

On the VM, **tomcat is running** and `curl http://1.2.3.4:8080` works.

[image]

But the same externally does not..

```
l-OSX: hal$ curl https://10.51.253.163:8080 -v
* Rebuilt URL to: https://10.51.253.163:8080/
*   Trying 10.51.253.163...
* connect to 10.51.253.163 port 8080 failed: Operation timed out
* Failed to connect to 10.51.253.163 port 8080: Operation timed out
```

**Tomcat's server.xml**

```
<Engine name="Catalina" defaultHost="10.51.253.163">
  ...
  <Host name="10.51.253.163" appBase="webapps"
        unpackWARs="true" autoDeploy="true">
```

**UFW is Inactive**

```
sudo ufw status verbose`
Status: inactive`
```

**Ping to the VM works**

```
l-OSX: hal$ ping 10.51.253.163
PING 10.51.253.163 (10.51.253.163): 56 data bytes
64 bytes from 10.51.253.163: icmp_seq=0 ttl=58 time=111.914 ms
64 bytes from 10.51.253.163: icmp_seq=1 ttl=58 time=93.793 ms
```

Appreciate any help on this!

Answer (score 0):

After some research and help from IT Support team, i was able to resolve this as below:

- VM > Manage Security
- Add Security Rule
- Allow Port: 8080 on Protocol: TCP

Able to access Tomcat from browser.

[image]